# Will Switch Case statement work with auto generated android resource id?

Tags: android

I'm using an android third-party library called nice spinner and implementing its ItemClickListener interface.
I have 3 NiceSpinner spinners in my layout and I want to use switch case statement on the onItemClick method for each NiceSpinner click event. 
This override method onItemClick returns adapterView as a parameter which is actually one of the NiceSpinner which is clicked. I have confirmed this by checking every NiceSpinner id and adapterView id in logcat during click event on every NiceSpinner. They are the same. So what I'm trying to achieve here is, by providing resource id of every NiceSpinner as a constant expression in this switch statement. These resource ids are auto-generated. My question is, will these resource ids be same in every android device which will install my android app?

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: " + adapterView.getId());
    TextView textView = (TextView) view;
    switch (adapterView.getId()) {
        case  2131296438 :

            break;
        case 2131296507 :

            break;
        case 2131296342 :

            break;

    }
}
```

[image]

Edit : As the statement in the comment by ViswanathKumarSandu  I had cleaned and rebuilt the project to check if auto generated ids are changed or not but ids are same. But now I have doubts about this approach. Can anyone suggest better reliable solution?

Comment: It doesn't work with auto generated IDs. When you clean and rebuild the app, new IDs can be generated. So never use auto generated code rely on

Comment: @ViswanathKumarSandu I think you are right. I will clean and rebuild and see the results.

Comment: @ViswanathKumarSandu I had cleaned and rebuilt the project but ids are same. But I have doubts about this approach. Can you suggest better reliable solution?

Comment: Do not use this approach. for Listview or RecyclerView, you need to use position to handle clicks. in the method definition, "long l" is the position of the item. Based on the position, you can handle the functionality

Comment: Actually, there are 3 spinners which are dependent on each other's selected result that's why I want to use switch case with resource ids. Anyway, I think better and safe option is to use if elseif.. else statement.